# Can Emacs detect the path of its executable?

Tags: elisp, system-environment

Suppose that I have two identical emacs (of the same version) on my system. One is placed at `C:\Program Files\Gnu Emacs` and the other one at different place, say `C:\Program Files\New Gnu Emacs`. Can a running Emacs detect which one is? For example, can it give the path of its executable (i.e., the path where emacs.exe or emacs.bin can be found)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming Emacs knows how it was started, you can access the full path
of the executable file by doing:

```
(expand-file-name invocation-name invocation-directory)
```

In my system, for instance, this returns `"/usr/local/bin/emacs"` on
my regular session and returns `"~/.evm/bin/emacs"` on my evm test
session. If you want to get fancy, you can also wrap that in a
[`file-truename`](http://doc.endlessparentheses.com/Fun/file-truename)
to resolve any symlinks.

---

The two variables used above, as described by their doc strings:

- [`invocation-name`](http://doc.endlessparentheses.com/Var/invocation-name)

  > The program name that was used to run Emacs.
  >   Any directory names are omitted.
- [`invocation-directory`](http://doc.endlessparentheses.com/Var/invocation-directory)

  > The directory in which the Emacs executable was found, to run it.
  >   The value is nil if that directory's name is not known.