# Is there a way Emacs can infer is running on WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux)?

Tags: conditionals, system-environment, wsl

I would like to identify when Emacs is running on [WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux).
Normally I use `system-type` variable to check if Emacs is on Linux, Windows or MacOS X.
Though in this case it returns `gnu/linux`:

```
system-type is a variable defined in ‘C source code’.
Its value is ‘gnu/linux’

Documentation:
The value is a symbol indicating the type of operating system you are using.
Special values:
  ‘gnu’          compiled for a GNU Hurd system.
  ‘gnu/linux’    compiled for a GNU/Linux system.
  ‘gnu/kfreebsd’ compiled for a GNU system with a FreeBSD kernel.
  ‘darwin’       compiled for Darwin (GNU-Darwin, macOS, ...).
  ‘ms-dos’       compiled as an MS-DOS application.
  ‘windows-nt’   compiled as a native W32 application.
  ‘cygwin’       compiled using the Cygwin library.
Anything else (in Emacs 26, the possibilities are: aix, berkeley-unix,
hpux, usg-unix-v) indicates some sort of Unix system.
```

Which is what it is expected, though...
I want to add a specific check to use the Windows native browser, not the one on WSL.
I currently do that setting:

```
(setq browse-url-browser-function 'my-browse-url-function)
```

But I only want to do this in WSL, not in real Linux.
Is there a way to do it?

Comment: A related question and answer https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/6010/

Answer (score 4):

You could also do `(string-match-p "Microsoft" (shell-command-to-string "uname -a"))`

Likely in your `my-browse-url-function` you're probably depending on a Windows
specific path to exist. You could just check that it exists and is executable
with `file-executable-p` like the following code does. However, this may not be
enough if you dual boot and mount the windows `C:` drive to the same mount
point.

```
;; setup browser function when running in WSL
(defconst powershell-exe "/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe")

(when (file-executable-p powershell-exe)
  (defun my\wsl-browse-url (url &optional _new-window)
    "Opens link via powershell.exe"
    (interactive (browse-url-interactive-arg "URL: "))
    (let ((quotedUrl (format "start '%s'" url)))
      (apply 'call-process powershell-exe
             nil 0 nil (list "-Command" quotedUrl))))

  (setq-default browse-url-browser-function 'my\wsl-browse-url))
```

Answer (score 4):

I just happened to notice this while looking for a an already implemented `wsl-browse-url` (thanks!), so will offer one other option:

```
(when (string-match "-[Mm]icrosoft" operating-system-release)
  ;; WSL: WSL1 has "-Microsoft", WSL2 has "-microsoft-standard"
  )
```

It looks like that works on both my Debian WLinux WSL 2 environments.

Comment: This one is available without further system calls. Nice!

Comment: Where is that `wsl-browse-url` function? I just made my own modifications to open native `chrome.exe` on WSL. which it might have problems in some cases, though I am happy with it.

Answer (score 3):

I would check for an environment variable using `getenv`. You may want to check what variables are available in your typical WSL shell, but one option would be to check for a Windows-specific PATH entry, perhaps:

```
(string-match-p "Windows" (getenv "PATH"))
```

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2017/12/22/share-environment-vars-between-wsl-and-windows/ would be relevant (found via https://stackoverflow.com/q/43794915 ).