if statement depending on machine identiy
I'm working on two different computers, both Linux. PC1 is a notebook. PC2 is a machine in an office, having a fixed IP, let's say 192.168.0.35.
In org mode files I'm using links to files. These links are supposed to work on both machines, despite the different paths. Solution: use abbreviations, offered by org-link-abbrev-alist. Let's say, "Goal1" is the abbreviation and on PC1 the link
Goal1:./my-file.org 

expands to "~/Documents/folderY/my-file.org" and on PC2 to "/mnt/ServerX/folderZ/my-file.org".
What I need is the lisp code, e.g. for my .emacs (or a file loaded at startup of emacs), that finds out, on which machine we are. The following code isn't working:
    (setq org-link-abbrev-alist
          (if (eq ip-address '192.168.0.35) ;; PC2 has this fixed IP
              '(("Goal1" . "/mnt/ServerX/Yfolder/%s"))
            '(("Goal1" . "~/Documents/folderY/%s"))))


Can you change that code snippet to working lisp code? OR:
Is there another way to check on which machine we are, maybe ask for the CPU-type or something else of the hardware? Is there a function in emacs for querying?


Why don't you use (system-name) (like $HOSTNAME in Bash) to distinguish between these two computers?...

If the executable path of your emacs on these machines are different you can possibly use the invocation-directory approch given in https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/6010/ to distingush between the systems.

In addition to system-name, as @shynur suggests, there are other system identifiers - see Operating System Environment in the Elisp Ref manual, e.g. system-configuration, system-type - which might help distinguish between the systems. But system-name is probably the most convenient.

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

@shynur I chose your suggestion, see answer below. I'm a user without (unfortunately) such common knowledge...

Thanks for the hint to (system-name) @shynur  in the comments. I never bothered to give a hostname to my machines, but now I have:
As superuser I entered in a terminal:
hostnamectl hostname PC123-Keks

After that,
hostnamectl status

confirmed the new hostname.
The lisp code in a file loaded by .emacs is something like
(setq org-agenda-files
  ( if (equal system-name "PC123-Keks")

and I've got a working solution.

Problem solved, congrats!  A suggestion: string= is faster than equal, so you can use string= instead.
